Inserting label in AgensGraph Function?
I'm trying to write plpgsql function using AgensGraph Cypher statements and I want to pass the label into the function as an argument.  I can set variables using:
CREATE FUNCTION testFunc("class" character varying) RETURNS character varying AS $$
DECLARE
result character varying;
BEGIN
MATCH (v:"person") WHERE v.'id' = $1 RETURN id(v) into result;
RETURN result;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;  

But it fails when I move the variable request into the vertex label position:
CREATE FUNCTION testFunc("class" character varying, "id" character varying) RETURNS character varying AS $$
DECLARE
result character varying;
BEGIN
MATCH (v: $1 ) WHERE v.'id' = $2 RETURN id(v) into result;
RETURN result;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;  

Does anyone know how to set the label name with a varible?
